# How to change view data when selecting option from dropdown, without having to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using [this example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-brushing.html) from `dc.js` to brush scatterplots.

I created a dropdown menu, with options being combinations of different dimensions; like `(x,y)`, `(x,z)`, `(y,z)`:

```
<select name="axes" class="ui dropdown" id="select">
    <option value="">Select Axes</option>
    <option value="xy">(x,y)</option>
    <option value="xz">(x,z)</option>
    <option value="yz">(y,z)</option>
</select>
```

Now every time I choose one of the options from the dropdown, I want the values in the scatterplot to change according to the dimensions that I picked. I tried the below code:

```
var val1 = "x", val2 = "y";
    $('#select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).dropdown('get value');
        if(val === "xz") {
            val1 = "x",
          val2 = "z";
        }
        if(val === "yz") {
            val1 = "y",
          val2 = "z";
        }
        if(val === "xy") {
            val1 = "x",
          val2 = "y";
        }
    });

var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d[val1], +d[val2]];
    });
```

But the values from the scatteplot do not change after I choose different dimensions.

How can I make the values of the scatterplot change "on the spot", after selecting an option from the dropdown?

[Running Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jundevlop/hmpgwdvs/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this would be to wrap the code inside a function, and call that function on `$('#select').change(function() {//call function here})`

```
function wrap(val1, val2) {

  ...

  var ndx = crossfilter(data),
      dim1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
          return [+d[val1], +d[val2]];
      }),
      group1 = dim1.group(),
  chart1.width(300)
      .height(300)
      .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
      .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
      .yAxisLabel(val2)
      .xAxisLabel(val1)
      .clipPadding(10)
      .dimension(dim1)
      .excludedOpacity(0.5)
      .group(group1);

  ...

}
```

Then you call this function once in the first load of the page, and then after every change in the dropdown menu:

```
$('select').val("xy").change(); // change the value in the dropdown on the first load   
var val1 = "x", val2 = "y";

$('#select').change(function() {
          var val = $(this).dropdown('get value');
          if(val === "xz") {
            val1 = "x",
            val2 = "z";
          }
          if(val === "yz") {
            val1 = "y",
            val2 = "z";
          }
          if(val === "xy") {
            val1 = "x",
            val2 = "y";
          }

          wrap(val1, val2);
      });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kenkaneki/hmpgwdvs/2/)

Comment: This is correct, though this function does more than it needs to do. I think all it really has to do is assign a new dimension to the chart and re-render the chart, rather than rebuild the whole crossfilter and all charts.

Comment: @EthanJewett yes you're right, it would be more efficient to leave the crossfilter data out of the wrap function. I'll relook it when I can, thank you

Comment: No worries - it is fine as is. Thanks for answering!